# Converting a org.w3c.dom.NodeList to a Clojure ISeq

Tags: collections, clojure

I am trying to get a handle on the new `defprotocol`, `reify`, etc.

I have a `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` returned from an XPath call and I would like to "convert" it to an ISeq.

In Scala, I implemented an implicit conversion method:

```
implicit def nodeList2Traversable(nodeList: NodeList): Traversable[Node] = {
  new Traversable[Node] {
    def foreach[A](process: (Node) => A) {
      for (index <- 0 until nodeList.getLength) {
        process(nodeList.item(index))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`NodeList` includes methods `int getLength()` and `Node item(int index)`.

How do I do the equivalent in Clojure? I expect that I will need to use `defprotocol`. What functions do I need to define to create a `seq`?

If I do a simple, naive, conversion to a list using `loop` and `recur`, I will end up with a non-lazy structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of Clojure's sequence-processing functions return lazy seqs, include the `map` and `range` functions:

```
(defn node-list-seq [^org.w3c.dom.NodeList node-list]
  (map (fn [index] (.item node-list index))
       (range (.getLength node-list))))
```

Note the type hint for NodeList above isn't necessary, but improves performance.

Now you can use that function like so:

```
(map #(.getLocalName %) (node-list-seq your-node-list))
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a [for comprehension](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/for), these yield lazy sequences.

Here's the code for you. I've taken the time to make it runnable on the command line; you only need to replace the name of the parsed XML file.

**Caveat 1:** avoid def-ing your variables. Use local variables instead.

**Caveat 2:** this is the Java API for XML, so there objects are mutable; since you have a lazy sequence, if any changes happen to the mutable DOM tree while you're iterating, you might have unpleasant race changes.

**Caveat 3:** even though this is a lazy structure, the whole DOM tree is already in memory anyway *(I'm not really sure about this last comment, though. I think the API tries to defer reading the tree in memory until needed, but, no guarantees)*. So if you run into trouble with big XML documents, try to avoid the DOM approach.

```
(require ['clojure.java.io :as 'io])
(import [javax.xml.parsers DocumentBuilderFactory])
(import [org.xml.sax InputSource])

(def dbf (DocumentBuilderFactory/newInstance))
(doto dbf
  (.setValidating false)
  (.setNamespaceAware true)
  (.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace true))
(def builder (.newDocumentBuilder dbf))
(def doc (.parse builder (InputSource. (io/reader "C:/workspace/myproject/pom.xml"))))

(defn lazy-child-list [element]
  (let [nodelist (.getChildNodes element)
        len (.getLength nodelist)]
    (for [i (range len)]
      (.item nodelist i))))

;; To print the children of an element
(-> doc
    (.getDocumentElement)
    (lazy-child-list)
    (println))

;; Prints clojure.lang.LazySeq
(-> doc
    (.getDocumentElement)
    (lazy-child-list)
    (class)
    (println))
```

Comment: Our posts crossed, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered.  Your use of 'for' looks very nice here.